# Read file by line and wait for keyboard input to read next line

Tags: common-lisp

A newbie question: (Common Lisp) read file by one line at a time and move to next by a keystroke.

There is a standard:

```
(let ((in (open "/some/file/name.txt" :if-does-not-exist nil)))
  (when in
    (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
        while line do (format t "~a~%" line))
    (close in)))
```

In the old Fortran I got accustomed to `wait` function which would somewhere in `(when in wait 'action...)`.

There are solutions in Clojure by way of `java.io`.

But what about JUST Common Lisp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, one should *always* use 
[`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm) instead of
[`open`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_open.htm)/[`close`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_close.htm).

Next, the ANSI CL standard does not specify i/o buffering, so there is
*no* standard way to make CL react to each keystroke.
You can, however, ask your user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Return</kbd>):

```
(with-open-file (in path)
  (loop for line = (read-line in nil nil)
    while line do
      (read-line)               ; wait for user to hit RET
      (format t "--> ~A~%" line)))
```

Comment: side question: if we had no buffering in some CL (but otherwise standard), would we be able to react to input without printing that input?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: if you did have a brother, would he liked potatoes? ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. The i/o stuff differs very much between languages, so this was indeed very important.